# c syntax error on common variables between different .c files

Tags: c, syntax

I am probably facing a syntax issue in c. I have main.c and test.c I am trying to use common variables.
file main.c

```
extern int a;
extern int b;
uint8_t matrix[(a+1)*b][4];
testFunction(matrix, 10)
```

file test.c

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
void testFunction(matrix[(a+1)*b][4], uint8_t z){
....}
```

If i compile I get error "variably modified at scope". I change the a+1 on main.c to 2 and I get the multiple definitions error. Any suggestions?

Comment: The definition for `void testFunction()` gives no *type* for the first parameter.

Comment: you cannot declare a prototype of a function with non-constant dimensions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure you can, use a VLA.

Comment: The error message you got was likely “variably modified 'matrix' at file scope”, not “variably modified at scope”. While we knew what you meant in this case, please copy and paste error messages **exactly** in the future. Details are important in computer programming.

Comment: @Lundin but not at global scope, and with variables as dimensions. that's what I meant.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Depends on what you mean with that. This will work: `void foo (size_t x, size_t y, int arr[x*y*42][666/y]);`. Though if you want to know the array size with sizeof, you need to swap it for an array pointer to prevent decay.

Comment: Although the problem the compiler is complaining about is that the code improperly attempts to define `matrix` with a variable size, the question is complicated by the fact that you are making `matrix` a global object defined in `main.c` in spite of the fact that `test.c` controls its size. This is a poor design that interferes with giving a nice answer. If `matrix` is to be a static object with a size known in `test.c`, it ought to be defined in `test.c`. And then there is no need for `main` to pass it as an argument to `testFunction`, since `test.c` already knows about it.…

Comment: … On the other hand, if `main` is going to pass `matrix` as an argument, then `matrix` likely should be defined in `main`. In that case, `main` needs to know the size, and setting it through global objects `a` and `b` defined in `test.c` is bad design. If you explain more of what you are ultimately trying to do here, better solutions can be suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare variable-length arrays at file scope. Nor is it a wise idea to use variables with external linkage for their size. What you probably want instead is this:

```
void testFunction (int x, int y, uint8_t matrix[x][y]);
```

Do the calculation of `x` and `y` in the caller, not as part of the function declaration.

(There *are* ways to do the size calculation in the function declaration, but they are messy and lead to unreadable code.)

Comment: The problem in the question is defining an array, not passing it to a function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You can't declare variable-length arrays at file scope. Nor is it a wise idea to use variables with external linkage for their size.

Comment: Yes, you cannot declare variable-length arrays at file scope. And so the OP needs an alternative. They need a method to define the array they want to define, whether it is a variable-length array at block scope or an allocated array or a constant-size array defined where the size is known. This answer presents no such solution. It does not answer the problem in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Variably modified array at file scope is not possible. In this case  the compiler `uint8_t matrix[(a+1)*b][4]` cannot determine the value of `a` and `b` when generating the object file. Even if it could, it is still an issue since the array is provisioned at the beginning in static memory and the variables can change any time. You can however have a variably modified array at blockscope.

Not sure about your exact requirements, but a solution to your problem in C99 might be to declare `testFunction` as:

```
void testFunction(int x, uint8_t matrix[x][4], uint8_t z) { ... }
```

And call it as:

```
#define AVAL 1
#define BVAL 2
int a= AVAL;
int b= BVAL;
uint8_t matrix[(AVAL+1)*BVAL][4];
testFunction((a+1)*b, matrix, 10);
```

Comment: It looks better in your way but still if I make the proposed changes I still get a "first defined" here error.

Comment: @kostas You need to adapt the prototype as well. The implementation only is not sufficient.

Comment: @kostas can you tell me the exact error. And which file you're getting the error in?

Answer (score -1):

If the size of your matrix is known at compile time, then you can define it as a global object, but its dimensions must be known (C *integer constant expressions*) where it is defined. If `test.c` knows the dimensions, it can define the matrix, as with:

```
#define a 1
#define b 2
uint8_t matrix[(a+1)*b][4];
```

Then the matrix can be accessed in `main.c` by declaring (but not defining) it there:

```
extern uint8_t matrix[][4];
```

If `main.c` also needs to know `a` and `b`, you can put those values in global objects, although you will need to use different names for those objects than for the preprocessor macros I have shown above. (Technically, there is a way to use the same names for both, but it is not generally recommended.)

If the size of your matrix is known at run time and not compile time, then you can create it using `malloc`. For example, in `main.c`, you could have:

```
extern uint8_t (*matrix)[4];

int main(void)
{
    … Ensure the values of a and b have been set.

    matrix = malloc((a+1)*b * sizeof *matrix);
    if (!matrix) … Handle error

    … Rest of program.

    free(matrix); // (Not strictly necessary in typical multi-user systems.)
}
```

In either case, I have shown the matrix made visible externally, because that is what you attempted in your code. However, since you pass the matrix to the function as a parameter, it is likely you do not need the matrix to be visible externally and do not need it to be defined with static storage duration. In this case, you can define it in main and pass it to the function:

```
int main(void)
{
    … Ensure the values of a and b have been set.

    uint8_t (*matrix)[4] = malloc((a+1)*b * sizeof *matrix);
    if (!matrix) … Handle error

    testFunction(matrix, z);
    … Rest of program.

    free(matrix); // (Not strictly necessary in typical multi-user systems.)
}
```

It is also possible to define the matrix inside `main`:

```
int main(void)
{
    … Ensure the values of a and b have been set.

    uint8_t matrix[(a+1)*b)][4];

    testFunction(matrix, z);
    … Rest of program.
}
```

However, this should be used only if `a` and `b` are known to be small. The resources available to provide array definitions at block scope like this are quite limited in most C implementations.

Comment: `uint8_t (*matrix)[4]` is a pointer, not an array. You didn't include the relevant headers stdlib.h and stdint.h, so this will cause bugs in C90. `… ` won't compile because it is not valid C, comments in C are written with `//` or `/*  */`. This won't work `uint8_t [(a+1)*b)][4];` because there is no variable name.

Comment: @Lundin: (a) Of course `uint8_t (*matrix)[4]` is a pointer, not an array. The answer does not say it is an array. In regard to that code, it says “you can create it [the array] using `malloc`.” Then the code creates the array using `malloc`. `matrix` is merely used to point to the allocated object. (b) The code in the question is already using declarations from `stdint.h`, so it is not necessary to state it; it is already implicit incorporated (and your answer using `uint8_t` without including `stdint.h` too). I have added `stdlib.h` explicitly.

Comment: @Lundin: (c) `…` is not intended to compile. As you well know, it merely marks where other code could go. (d) I have fixed the missing name.